# Spring Redis Data repository: get multiple hashes by ids at once

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

### Question

*Is there any way to use Spring Data Redis' repositories to retrieve multiple hashes at once?*

My code that does not work:

```
@RedisHash("Message")
public class Message implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String text;
    private LocalDateTime posted;
    private Integer upvotes;
    private String authorId;
}

@Repository
public interface MessageRepository extends CrudRepository<Message, String> {
    // Got: IN (1): [IsIn, In]is not supported for redis query derivation
    Set<Message> getByIdIn(Set<String> ids); 
}
```

### Workaround

Currently I'm using `RestTemplate#executePipelined`, but I found this approach cumbersome:

```
public Set<Message> getMessagesById(Set<String> ids) {

        // I had to implement custom mapper since BeanUtilsHashMapper fails on LocalDateTime deserialization from String
        HashMapper<Message, String, String> mapper = new DTOConverter<>(Message.class);

        List<Object> messages = template.executePipelined((RedisCallback<Object>) connection -> {
            StringRedisConnection conn = (StringRedisConnection) connection;
            ids.stream()
                    .map(id -> "Message:" + id)
                    .forEach(conn::hGetAll);
            return null;
        });

        return messages.stream()
                .map(o -> (Map<String, String>) o)
                .map(o -> mapper.fromHash(o))
                .collect(toSet());
}
```

*Is there any way to pass `mapper` to `executePipelined`?*

Comment: shouldn't that be *findByIdIn* :  _Set<Message> findByIdIn(Set<String> ids);_

Comment: @DirkDeyne thank! My bad. Does `findByIdIn` use pipelining or scripting under the hood?

Comment: @DirkDeyne looks like Spring Data Redis does not support `IN`. I got: `IN (1): [IsIn, In]is not supported for redis query derivation`

Comment: yeah, unfortunate.... [Supported query keywords](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords) but  
there is a warning: However, consult the store-specific documentation for the exact list of supported keywords, because some keywords listed here might not be supported in a particular store...

Comment: on the other hand... in a CrudRepository **Iterable<T> findAllById(Iterable<ID> ids);** is available.

Comment: @DirkDeyne yes, it works! Do you know the way to check how it works under the hood? Is there something like show_sql for redis?

Comment: from the documentation: _findByLastnameAndFirstname_  translates into
_SINTER …:firstname:rand …:lastname:al’thor_ [repository-query-keywords](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords)